# PostgreSQL JDBC socket timeout doesn't kill background process

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, timeout

I'm using JDBC to run queries against my PostgreSQL DB.  When the queries take too long I want them to die.  I set `socketTimeout` (as shown below), which does successfully kill the connection, but if I look at `pg_stat_activity` on the PostgreSQL server, the query often continues to run (for up to a few minutes).

My code looks a little like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", datasource.getUsername());
props.setProperty("password", datasource.getPassword());
props.setProperty("socketTimeout", ""+(timeoutSeconds));
props.setProperty("loginTimeout", "10");
conn = datasource.getDbType().getDriver().connect(url, props);
conn.setReadOnly(true);
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
return statement.executeQuery();
```

My assumption is that `socketTimeout` literally just kills the connection, but not the running process on the postgres server. I.e., this timeout is driver-side not PostgreSQL-side.

**Is there a way to set a timeout (on a per-statement level) that will actually make PostgreSQL kill the query itself after a given timeout?**

Note: I have found one solution so far, which is to explictly cancel the query after a given timeout (i.e. `using statement.cancel()`).  This works, but isn't ideal, since if my server dies, then nobody will kill the running queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT).

Comment: Hi.  How can I do that from my JDBC statement above? (I need the timeout to be per-statement, i.e. each statement may have a different timeout)

Comment: conn.createStatement().execute("set statement_timeout to "+timeoutSeconds);// this seems to do the trick